# vue-router how to use params in v-for when is change

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I click 1, the root and the component in v-for is show 1. when I click 2, the root show 2 the component show 1 yet.

how to change value in v-for when I click another. such as

```
click/1 -> doorA_1
click/2 -> doorA_2
```

thanks.
here is the link:
[`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/tanjw/tba7nnww)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `v-once` of `my-table`

```
<div :class = "[tableindex % 2 == 0 ? \'doorA\' : \'doorB\']" v-once>
```

should be

```
<div :class = "[tableindex % 2 == 0 ? \'doorA\' : \'doorB\']">
```